# Do audit table APIs exist for MongoDB that can be used along with another SQL database?

Tags: sql, mongodb, audit-tables

Do [audit-table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25695/how-are-transactions-logs-inserted) APIs exist for MongoDB used together with some other SQL database, that can be told to automatically mimic a normal SQL table's structure, and trigger inserts into that table's MongoDB table-histories at the end of a commit?  If so, what are these types of APIs generally referred to as?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (as at MongoDB 2.4) any sort of data history/versioning feature included in the server.

I'm not aware of any standard terminology for this pattern. Depending on your use case you may be thinking of "versioning", "archiving", or "auditing" and these could have different connotations on what you expect to happen with the data (i.e. full documents, diffs, ...).

You can, of course, implement these patterns in your application code.

There may be existing libraries depending on your development language.  For example, [Vermongo](https://github.com/thiloplanz/v7files/wiki/Vermongo) implements a document versioning scheme in Java.

If you have a [replica set configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/), you also could use the [`oplog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) and a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) to roll your own solution.